# $\sum X_n$ converges a.s.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

This one is from old qualifying exam.

$\{X_n\}$ be **non-negative, independent** and $\{Y_n\}$ is another sequence (not necessarily independent) but $X_n \sim^{d} Y_n$. Then $\sum X_n$ converges a.s. $\Rightarrow$ $\sum Y_n$ will also converge a.s.

(This part I am able to show using Kolmogorov 3-series and Khintchine Equivalence. But I am stuck at the following)

**Question**: If non-negativity is dropped from $X_n$'s we can not conclude the convergence of $\sum Y_n$.

Any kind of help/hint is appreciated. Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Example**: Let $X_n\sim N(0,n^{-2})$ (independent) and $Y_n=n^{-1}Z$ where $Z\sim N(0,1)$. Then $X_n\overset{d}{=} Y_n$ and $\sum X_n\to X$ in distribution (and hence $a.s.$), where $X\sim N\left(0,\pi^2/6\right)$. However,

$$
\sum_{n=1}^N Y_n(\omega)=Z(\omega)\sum_{n=1}^N n^{-1}
$$

which does not converge in $\mathbb{R}$ for $Z(\omega)\ne 0$.